# Which cam used as PoV?

Tags: camera

On Blender 3.3
I open my file where Ctl-0 has been made on one of my 2 cameras, very narrow shift so visual no difference.
But when I open my file, no camera is selected.
How can I know, on which camera has been made Ctl-0 Point Of View (but without visual way) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Active camera has a camera icon with highlighted background:

[image]

Also you can see active camera in scene properties:

[image]

Comment: OK, indeed I see. Thank you !